# Import data from excel and consolidate

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm using the below code to read from an excel file and add certain columns into a listview. Once imported i'm then exporting them to a CSV (code not shown).

My problem is that the excel file is a till extract and it displays the data by transaction which results in thousands of lines. I would like to perform the excel equivalent of `SUMIF` based on the EPoS line and consolidate the info if thats possible?

Sample of data below...

[image: Sample Info]

```
    Public Structure ExcelRows
    Dim Unit As String
    Dim Outlet As String
    Dim EPoS As String
    Dim Quantity As String
    Dim Value As String
    Dim DateSale As String

End Structure
Public ExcelRowList As List(Of ExcelRows) = New List(Of ExcelRows)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Public Function GetInfo() As Boolean
    Dim Completed As Boolean = False
    Dim MyExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim enUK As New CultureInfo("en-GB")
    Dim DOS As String = "01/04/15"
    MyExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Dropbox\Tills\taRunAction1.xlsx")

    MyExcel.Sheets("Report").Activate()
    MyExcel.Range("A10").Activate()

    Dim ThisRow As New ExcelRows

    Do
        If MyExcel.ActiveCell.Value > Nothing Or MyExcel.ActiveCell.Text > Nothing Then

            ThisRow.Unit = MyExcel.ActiveCell.Value
            MyExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()

            ThisRow.Outlet = MyExcel.ActiveCell.Value
            MyExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()

            ThisRow.DateSale = MyExcel.ActiveCell.Value

            MyExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Activate()

            ThisRow.EPoS = MyExcel.ActiveCell.Value
            MyExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()

            ThisRow.Quantity = MyExcel.ActiveCell.Value
            MyExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()

            ThisRow.Value = MyExcel.ActiveCell.Value

            ExcelRowList.Add(ThisRow)
            MyExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(1, -6).Activate()

        Else
            Completed = True
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop
    MyExcel.Workbooks.Close()
    MyExcel = Nothing

    Return Completed

End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If GetInfo() = True Then

        For Each xItem In ExcelRowList

            Dim lViewItem As ListViewItem

            lViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(xItem.Unit)
            lViewItem.SubItems.AddRange(New String() {xItem.Outlet, xItem.EPoS, xItem.Quantity, xItem.Value, xItem.DateSale})

        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use a DataTable:

```
Private dt As DataTable
...
dt = New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("EPOS", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("Unit", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(Decimal))
dt.Columns.Add("Total", GetType(Decimal))
dt.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))

Dim keys As DataColumn() = {dt.Columns("EPOS")}
dt.PrimaryKey = keys
```

It is not clear whether "VALUE" is the Unit Price or Sale Amount because all the units are 1.  I am not sure I would repeat data such as the SaleDate over and over,  The key is that the DataTable could *replace* the XLRows Structure.

One key is that you want to work with properly Typed data so you can multiply and add.  The XLRow structure is *not* properly typed - everything is string rather than Date, Decimal, Integer etc.

#### A. XLRow Class to Convert

For this, convert the XLRow structure to a class.  Its role would be to take in string data from XL and convert to Typed data.  Next, the DataTable is used to collect the rollup data.

For this, the `PrimaryKey` definition above is critical.  It will prevent you from adding a second (or 1000th) "Pepsi" item and allow you to find that summary item.  Perhaps best of all, you can get rid of the `ListView` and use a `DataGridView`:

```
dgv.DataSource = dt
```

[image]

With **one** line of code, the DGV will create the columns and display all the rows in the DataTable.  Unlike a ListView it will update itself as the underlying data in the DataTable changes.  To iterate your data to summarize inside a loop:

```
' get the row for this EPOS code
Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Rows.Find(xl.EPOS)

If dr IsNot Nothing Then
    ' we already have this item, increment Quan, TotalSales:
    dr("Quantity") += xl.Quantity
    dr("Total") += (xl.Quantity * xl.Value)
Else
    ' new transaction item, add it:
    dt.Rows.Add(xl.EPOS, xl.Unit, xl.Quantity, 
           xl.Value, (xl.Quantity * xl.Value), xl.DateSale)
End If
```

This is pretty concise, because as you read data from XL, it is added to the Summary.  There is no need to import all the detail data (XLS rows) into a collection or datatable before you perform the rollup.

---

#### B.  Use Linq instead of the XLRow structure

For this **omit the Primary Key** in the DataTable.  In this case, the DataTable would collect the raw XLS data instead of the XLRow structure. *Do* convert to numerics for the rollup. Next, use linq to summarize the data; perhaps into another DataTable.  Example:

Sample Data:

```
dt.Rows.Add(10001, "Ginger Ale", 1, 2.25, #4/5/2015#)
dt.Rows.Add(34582, "Pepsi", 3, 6.0, #4/5/2015#)
dt.Rows.Add(10002, "Chips", 1, 3.25, #4/5/2015#)
dt.Rows.Add(34582, "Pepsi", 1, 2.0, #4/5/2015#)
dt.Rows.Add(78301, "Roast Duck", 1, 15.25, #4/5/2015#)
dt.Rows.Add(34582, "Pepsi", 1, 2.0, #4/5/2015#)
dt.Rows.Add(34582, "Pepsi", 1, 2.0, #4/5/2015#)
dt.Rows.Add(10002, "Chips", 1, 3.25, #4/5/2015#)
dt.Rows.Add(34582, "Pepsi", 1, 2.0, #4/5/2015#)
```

To get the summary info:

```
' group the data by EPOS code
Dim drs = From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
          Group row By ID = row.Field(Of Integer)("EPOS") Into Group
          Select Group

Dim TotSales As Decimal
Dim TotUnits As Integer

' each DRS is a collection of all the items with the same EPOS code
Dim dr As DataRow()

Console.WriteLine("EPOS     Item    Lines   Units   Total Sales")
' get the total sales in each group
For n As Integer = 0 To drs.Count - 1
    dr = drs(n)         ' the current EPOC group

    TotUnits = dr.Sum(Function(t) t.Field(Of Integer)("Quantity"))

    ' Sales could just be TotUnits * dr(0)("Value")
    ' sample data makes it unclear if Value is the UNITPRICE or SALEAMOUNT
    ' This assumes it is SALEAMOUNT such that 2 Pepsi = 4.00
    TotSales = dr.Sum(Function(t) t.Field(Of Decimal)("Value"))

    ' ToDo: do something interesting with the totals
    Console.WriteLine("{0}      {1}      {2}         {3}     {4}",
                    dr(0)("EPOS"),
                    dr(0)("Unit").ToString,
                    dr.Length.ToString("D2"),
                    TotUnits.ToString,
                    TotSales.ToString("C2"))
Next
```

The output:

```
EPOS     Item          Lines   Units   Total Sales  
10001     Ginger Ale     01       1     $2.25
34582     Pepsi          05       7     $14.00
10002     Chips          02       2     $6.50
78301     Roast Duck     01       1     $15.25
```

The key is that it does act much like SUMIF once you have the Typed data in a useful structure.  The result shows that the data has 5 Pepsi entries, 7 total units and 7*2 = 14.

I think the loop version is slightly easier to manage and debug, and it much more economical since the Summary is built on the fly as XLS rows are read in.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll have a look at these later. I don't really need to see the data in a ListView or Data table as the output into a structured consolidated format is what i'm looking for (this currently works from my listview). With regards to reading into OleDB, the file will always be an Excel file and there is a number of deadlines and other info at the top of the file thats not required.

Answer (score 0):

@Plutonix's answer is a good idea and I totally agree with his comments about changing your ExcelRows structure/class fields from strings to the appropriate numerical type.

Another possibility is to use LINQ to group the data from your ExcelRowList.  Something like the following

```
Dim results = From r In ExcelRowList
              Group By r.EPoS
              Into Group, Sum(r.Value * r.Quantity)
```

Note that this won't work as is because r.Value and r.Quantity are strings so you can't multiply them.  So you should change the field types in your structure and then when you are looping through the cells, cast the cell value to the correct type.  You will have to decide what to do if the cast fails.

[Group By on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531412(v=vs.140).aspx).